# Nested CSS Tables - Nested table width is width of the first column

Tags: html, css, nested, width, css-tables

I'm attempting to have some information for an element in columns (one, two, three, four - in the example). That element has child elements (five, six, seven, eight - in the example). I'm attempting to have the child element be 95% width of the parent table_div, however, it is 95% width of the first column of the parent table_div.

The goal is something that looks like the Reddit comment layout in terms of indentation. How do I get that child element to be the same width as the parent element, instead of the same width as the first column?

HTML:

```
<div class='table_div root'>
    <div class='table_row'>
        <span class='table_cell'>one</span>
        <span class='table_cell'>two</span>
        <span class='table_cell'>three</span>
        <span class='table_cell'>four</span>
    </div>

    <div class='table_div child'>
        <div class='table_row'>
            <span class='table_cell'>five</span>
            <span class='table_cell'>six</span>
            <span class='table_cell'>seven</span>
            <span class='table_cell'>eight</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.table_div {
    display: table;
    width:100%;
}

.table_row {
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
}

.table_cell {
    display: table-cell;
}

.root {
    width: 100%;
}

.child {
    width: 95%;  
    margin-left: 5%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z168q2xg/2/

Comment: Why not use actual TABLE tags instead of hacking DIVs?

Comment: Because it's not great practice to use tables for layout, and some of those table-cell spans may turn into more complex elements than text.

Comment: Turning DIVs into table cells amounts to the same thing: you're using tables for layout. What you really need is Flexbox. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/flexbox/quick/

Comment: I'm open to using that, got any examples of tables that I could modify as a proof of concept? I want to make sure nested tables work before trying to learn it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div class='comments'>
    <div class='comment-container'>
        <div class='comment-header'>
            <div class='comment-user'>Test User 1</div>
            <div class='comment-date'>03/04/2015 2:12 PM</div>
            <div class='comment-id'>3221</div>
        </div>
        <div class='comment-body'>This is my sample comment.</div>
        <div class='comment-replies'>
            <div class='comment-container'>
                <div class='comment-header'>
                    <div class='comment-user'>Test User 3</div>
                    <div class='comment-date'>03/04/2015 2:13 PM</div>
                    <div class='comment-id'>3232</div>
                </div>
                <div class='comment-body'>Replying to commentor</div>
                <div class='comment-replies'></div>
            </div>
            <div class='comment-container'>
                <div class='comment-header'>
                    <div class='comment-user'>Test User 4</div>
                    <div class='comment-date'>03/04/2015 2:15 PM</div>
                    <div class='comment-id'>3241</div>
                </div>
                <div class='comment-body'>OMG Another comment</div>
                <div class='comment-replies'></div>
            </div>
            <div class='comment-container'>
                <div class='comment-header'>
                    <div class='comment-user'>Test User 7</div>
                    <div class='comment-date'>03/04/2015 2:16 PM</div>
                    <div class='comment-id'>3521</div>
                </div>
                <div class='comment-body'>This is my sample comment.</div>
                <div class='comment-replies'>
                    <div class='comment-container'>
                        <div class='comment-header'>
                            <div class='comment-user'>Test User 1</div>
                            <div class='comment-date'>03/04/2015 2:12 PM</div>
                            <div class='comment-id'>3621</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='comment-body'>This is my sample comment.</div>
                        <div class='comment-replies'></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='comment-container'>
        <div class='comment-header'>
            <div class='comment-user'>Test User 2</div>
            <div class='comment-date'>03/04/2015 2:15 PM</div>
            <div class='comment-id'>4221</div>
        </div>
        <div class='comment-body'>Replying to OP</div>
        <div class='comment-replies'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.comments {
    display: block;
    width:100%;
    background-color: #CCFFFF;
}
.comment-container {
    display: block;
    width:95%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.comment-container + .comment-container {
    border-top: 0px;
}
.comment-replies {
    border-right: 0px solid black;
}
.comment-replies > .comment-container {
    margin-left:5%;
    border-right: 1px ;
    border-bottom: 0px;
}
.comment-replies .comment-replies {
     border-right: 0px;
}
.comment-user {
    width: 25%;
    background-color: #99FFCC;
}
.comment-date {
    width: 40%;
    background-color: #C2C2FF;
}
.comment-id {
    float: right;
    background-color: #FFCC99;
    width: 35px;
    margin-right: 0px !important;
}
.comment-header > div {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z168q2xg/15/

Comment: This doesn't include the column layout.

Comment: @douggard you can replace the `comment-text` element with the desired structure. I'm in a meeting at the moment, but I will update the example after.

Comment: That causes child elements at the same depth to not have their columns line up. http://jsfiddle.net/z168q2xg/5/

Comment: Why do children need to line up with the parent? Are you putting data in the other 'columns'  or are they for something like buttons.

Comment: Children need to line up with other children at the same depth, not with the parents. I would like this because it looks good. Unaligned data is difficult to look at. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/z168q2xg/7/ but with the child elements have 95% width of parent, not of the first column of the parent.

Comment: That looks like the best solution I'll get. If you want to edit your answer to include it I will accept. Thank you!

Comment: the key is making sure that your columns have a width set. otherwise the text will just be jumbled together.